# How to get selected item on model dialog box on rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, drop-down-menu

I'm developing project on rails 2.3.8 and I need to get selected item on dropdown menu in model dialog box. Please can someone explain how to do it on model dialog box on rails ?

Comment: The question is very vague, and appears to be a question related more to JavaScript than Rails.  You need to define what you mean by "get selected item".  Do you want to immediately submit the value?  Or store it and submit later?  Also, what are the scenarios in which  you want to take action? e.g. When the modal box is closed, or when the user changes the selection.

Comment: I need to update a particular div when user select a particular item on drop down menu. But I try to do it using observe_field but it didn't work for me. I'm using "collection_select" drop down menu. So I need to know whether it's possible or not on rails. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's very possible.  I have little experience with Prototype and it was a long time ago, so I'm afraid I'm not much help when it comes to setting up observe_field.  My first thought, however, is that an event callback is not being registered or a JavaScript error.  Can you verify that your JavaScript code is executed when the drop-down box is changed?  If so, are there any errors occurring?

Comment: I try to implement observe field on normal drop down menu on JQuery model dialog box but it doesn't work can you please explain how to do it on rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example which will work with some adjustment, as you have given no code (give code and people will be able to give specific answers):

In the view something like this is produced by a form helper:

```
<select id="user_role_ids" name="user[role_ids]">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Reader</option>
<option value="2">Author</option>
</select>
<div id="role_output"></div>
```

In JS with jquery something like this to extract name or id of model in select:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$("select").change(function () {
    var text = $('#user_role_ids option:selected').text()
    var value = $('#user_role_ids option:selected').val()
    $('#role_output').html(text+" =>"+value)
});
</script>
```

No need to involve rails at all unless you want to trigger an action in the controller as well, in which case post from jquery to an action set up specifically for it rather than extracting values:

```
$.post('/controller/my_action', ...);
```

That is all that observe_field does, and depending on what you want, you may not need it.